# Erro segmentation fault sem consegiu indentificar

Tags: c

Olá, amigos!

Estou criando um programa que irá ler um texto. Esse texto deverá ser alocado uma linha por vez (com até 75 caracteres por linha).

O programa recebe, na entrada ,o texto do usuário até que a string "the end!" seja digitada.

Contudo ao executar o programa, estou tendo o erro: Segmentation fault (core dumped). (Detalhe: Este erro me é comum, e por várias vezes já tentei resolvê-lo, mas sem sucesso). Por favor, digam o porquê de este erro acontecer, não só nesse código como também as suas causas comuns.)

Posteriormente, eu irei usar a função stringUpper para deixar o meu texto com letras maiúsculas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_CHAR 75

const char THE_END[] = "the end!";
void stringUpper(char*, int);

void main() {
    char **texto;
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    texto = NULL;
    for( ; ; ) {
        texto = (char**)realloc(texto,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
        texto[i] = (char*)malloc(MAX_CHAR*sizeof(char));
        fgets(texto[i],MAX_CHAR,stdin);
        texto[strlen(texto[i]-1)] = '\0'; // troca o '\n' (úlimo dígito da string) pelo terminador nulo
        if(strcmp(THE_END,texto[i]) == 0) break;
        i++;
    }

    for(j = 0; j < i; i++) {
        free(texto[j]);
    }

    free(texto);






}

void stringUpper(char *s, int tam) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O amigo Emoon achou a primeira parte do problema na resposta dele, que o `fgets` põe um `\n` no final da string lida e que precisa dar `free` em cada uma das strings alocadas.

Quanto a esse `\n`, a solução seria substituí-lo por `\0` e foi isso que você fez. Ou melhor, foi isso que você **tentou fazer**!

Você fez esse código para substituir o `\n` por `\0`:

```
texto[strlen(texto[i]-1)] = '\0';
```

Isso está errado. O correto seria isso:

```
texto[i][strlen(texto[i]) - 1] = '\0';
```

Depois, na hora de desalocar as strings, veja o seu laço:

```
for(j = 0; j < i; i++)
```

Esse laço está errado! Era para ser `j++` ao invés de `i++`.

Arrumando esses probleminhas, o código funcionou para mim como o esperado.

Comment: Você tem razão. O pior de tudo é que cometi esses 2 erros por pura falta de atenção, mas, na hora de (tentar) corrigir, não consegui perceber. Eu sou bastante desatento, você acha que isso é ruim pra quem é programador? Você acha que isso pode prejudicar minha carreira ou não tem problema?(Deixa aqui nos comentários a sua resposta. Desde já agradeço) :)

Comment: Agora, está tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: @L.Pedro Se a resposta serviu, não esqueça de clicar no ✅ verde para marcar esta resposta como correta/aceita.

Comment: Era isso que eu ia comentar também, ele estava atribuindo `\0` a um ponteiro, ou seja, o mesmo que NULL. +1 por complementar a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Existem alguns problemas no seu programa. `strcmp`, em caso de igualdade, devolve 0, e não o contrário. Além disso, o `fgets` possui o inconveniente de não eliminar o `\n` ao final da entrada. Você pode corrigir isso substituindo-o por um `\0` ou colocando-o na comparação. Uma possível solução então seria:

```
if (strcmp("the end!\n", texto[i]) == 0) break;
```

Além disso, não se esqueça de que você precisa dar `free` não só no endereço de `texto`, mas em cada uma das linhas também.

Não consegui recriar seu SegFault, mas o problema pode estar nesse `realloc` que é chamado quando o ponteiro `texto` contém inicialmente lixo. Tente fazer um `malloc` para ele antes.

Comment: Olá, Emoon! Eu fiz as modificações que eram necessárias. Contudo, no que diz respeito ao "Segmentation fault", ele continua aparecendo mesmo se eu fizer um malloc antes.

Comment: Você poderia rodar o `gdb` para descobrir exatamente em que linha está acontecendo esse SegFault?

Answer (score 0):

Eu terminei o código. Ele está assim agora:

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #define MAX_CHAR 75

const char THE_END[] = "the end!";
void stringUpper(char*, int);
void clearBuffer();
void textUpper(char**,int);
void printText(char**,int);
char **desalocaTexto(char**,int);

void main() {
    char **texto;
    int i = 0;
    int j;
    texto = NULL;
    for( ; ; ) {
        texto = (char**)realloc(texto,(i+1)*sizeof(char*));
        texto[i] = (char*)malloc(MAX_CHAR*sizeof(char));
        //clearBuffer();
        fgets(texto[i],MAX_CHAR,stdin);
        texto[i][strlen(texto[i]) - 1] = '\0';// troca o '\n' (úlimo dígito da string) pelo terminador nulo

        if(strcmp(THE_END,texto[i]) == 0) break;
        i++;
    }

    textUpper(texto, i);
    printText(texto,i);

    texto = desalocaTexto(texto,i);
}

void stringUpper(char *s, int tam) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        s[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
}


void clearBuffer() {
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

}

void textUpper(char **texto ,int tam) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        stringUpper(texto[i],MAX_CHAR);
    }
}

void printText(char **texto,int tam) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++) {
        printf("%s\n",texto[i]);
    }

}

char **desalocaTexto(char **t ,int linhas) {
    int j;
    for(j = 0; j < linhas; j++) {
        free(t[j]);
    }

    free(t);
    return NULL;
}
```

Pessoal, considerando que eu sou um iniciante, o código está bem feito na opnião de vocês? Em quanto tempo em média eu posso me tornar um profissional em C?

Comment: O código está bem feito e indentado, só algumas falhas de consistência no espaçamento que poderiam ser corrigidas.

Comment: Agora, a questão é, você *realmente* quer se tornar um profissional em C? É bom saber o básico da linguagem, isso não nego, mas profissionalmente você irá querer trabalhar com algo mais robusto e orientado a objeto. E C++ existe justamente pra isso, que basicamente contém tudo de C com a vantagem de ser uma linguagem moderna e tão eficiente quanto

Comment: Não me leve a mal, C até tem suas finalidades didáticas, como ensinar conceitos de baixo nível como ponteiros e endereços, mas infelizmente impera um conservadorismo (ao menos é o que vejo na minha universidade), de professores com a cabeça mergulhada a 20 anos no passado, de querer usá-la pra quase tudo. E infelizmente acabamos nos apegando erroneamente a ela

Comment: Emoon, obrigado. :)